# Install OpenDevin with Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am having difficulties understanding how to install OpenDevin with the provided docker image. In the README on GitHub, the following first installation steps are mentioned:

#### Installation

First, make sure Docker is running:

```bash
docker ps # this should exit successfully
```

Then pull our latest image [here](https://github.com/opendevin/OpenDevin/pkgs/container/sandbox).

```bash
docker pull ghcr.io/opendevin/sandbox:v0.1
```

Then start the backend:

```bash
export OPENAI_API_KEY="..."
export WORKSPACE_DIR="/path/to/your/project"
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
uvicorn opendevin.server.listen:app --port 3000
```

I do not understand where I "start the backend"? Do I need to run something like `docker run (...)` in a terminal window and then type these commands? Or do I have to clone the repository as well in order to have the requirements.txt file available for Python to know what modules it needs to install?

If I have to clone the repo locally, what's the goal then in pulling a Docker image? Isn't the goal of Docker to have everything in a "container", so that everything is in one place? Wouldn't the Python module have to be already installed in that Docker image?

I have Docker, Python and Node.js installed.

Comment: This question is meant for the maintainer of the codebase i.e. they need to update their documentation. The steps that they have mentioned in their documentation are not correct, you need to create a Github issue in their repository explaining the problem that you have faced. IMO if the steps are clear and yet you are not able to get started then you can post question on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work thanks to this video:

```
[OpenDevin: AI Software Engineer With Complex Coding Completion][1]
```

One first needs to clone the [OpenDevin repo](https://github.com/OpenDevin/OpenDevin/tree/main) and run `requirements.txt` from within this repo.